# Слово "ромалы" может иметь переносное значение?

Tags: значение-слов

1. Из современной художественной **фантастики**.

Хозяин магического трактира недоволен маленькими мушками, которые незаконно вывелись у него на кухне.

... Я им говорю: ***«Деньги давайте, ромалы!»*** А они мне: «А мы мамашу не просили нас рожать!»

2. В толковом словаре **слова "ромалы" нет**, а на сайте Грамота.ру можно найти такую информацию:

№ 254522
Здравствуйте. Пожалуйста, не оставьте без внимания. Как правильно: ромалЫ или ромалЭ? Заранее спасибо! ОТВЕТ. Если речь идет о **самоназвании цыган**, следует употреблять вариант ***рома*** (ударение на А).

Comment: ромалы - это цыгане. Да может иметь. Слово цыгане тоже может иметь переносное значение. Но не очень понятно, почем хозяин "магического трактира" разговаривает  с мухами, а они ему ещё что-то отвечают.

Comment: Думаете, с головой не все в порядке?  Нет, у него особая муха, сказочница. Вот придумал Чуковский сказку про Муху-Цокотуху в 1924 году.  За 100 лет ее сколько раз перечитали, что энергетика материализовалась и теперь муха как бы настоящая.  Хозяин печалится: "Совсем эти сказочники обнаглели!" В знаменитом стихотворении блошки подарили Мухе-Цокотухе сапожки, да не простые, а с золотыми застежками, очень они пришлись по вкусу Мухе-Цокотухе. Вы тоже сказку в детстве читали и эту муху представляли себе. Вот и результат.

Comment: А какое переносное значение имеет слово "ромалы"?  Оно мне почему-то нравится, но в какой бы ситуации его использовать? А можно ударение так ставить: ромАлы?

Comment: А, то есть это дети Мухи-Цокотухи? Ну тогда тут "ромалы" это эвфемизм указывающий на незаконнорождённых поселенцев, ну чтобы не говорить "ублюдки в этакие" автор решил заменить более благозвучным "ромалы" - мол откуда вы тут понаехали прикочевали.  Ну ударение всегда было ромАлы вроде, не ромалЫ же и не рОмалы. Румыны короче)

Comment: Спасибо, смешно! Я только не могу понять,  почему мне иногда хочется использовать это слово.  "Ромалы"  по фонетике похоже не только на румын,  но и на представителей романской культуры или римлян.  Кого в переносном смысле можно назвать ромалами?

Comment: Кого можно назвать цыганами... ну плутоватых и вороватых нелегалов можно). Хотя может и певучих соседей.)